# Java Selenium checking checkbox label status

Tags: java, css, html, selenium, input

I am doing Selenium automatization app and I don't know how to check for checkbox input status. Maybe someone had this issue also?

This is working example in js+jquery

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).is(":checked"));
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //true
    } else {
        //false
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/67j8xhy0/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you really want you can try by xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type="checkbox")).isSelected()
```

But if you have an ID of the checkbox you can do

```
driver.findElement(By.id("checkbox-id")).isSelected()
```

Here's the doc: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isSelected--

Answer (score -2):

You can use the code below either one would work but preferably I would use xpath which almost always works:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath/id/csssector("enter your data")).isSelected();
```

Comment: What new did your answer bring to the topic that hasn't already been said?